# avoid successful broadcast of a scalar

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector, scalar

When [subtracting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.subtract.html) or [multiplying](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html) arrays, numpy [*broadcasts*](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) them to the same shape:

```py
>>> np.array(((2,3),(4,5))) - np.array((1,2,3,4))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,2) (4,) 
>>> np.array((2,3,4,5)) - np.array((1,2,3,4))
array([1, 1, 1, 1])
>>> np.array((2,3,4,5)) - np.array(1)
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> np.array((2,3,4,5)) * np.array(2)
array([ 4,  6,  8, 10])
```

while the last operation makes sense [*mathematically*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra) (one *can* multiply a [vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) by a [scalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_(mathematics))), the penultimate one does *not* (one *cannot* add or subtract a scalar to a vector).

I wonder if it is possible to tell numpy ***not*** to broadcast scalars to
vectors or matrices in additive context, raising `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together` instead.

#### Rationale: the difference between *multiplying* each element of an array by a scalar, and adding the *scalar* to each element of the array

A vector is an element of a [Vector
space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space), i.e., an [Abelian
group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group) whose elements can
additionally be multiplied by a
[scalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_(mathematics)), i.e., a number.
IOW, *multiplying* a vector (or a matrix) by a number is a natural operation
with well defined properties like [distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) &c.

However, *adding* a *scalar* to a *vector* is not defined *at all*.

Why?! Because you **cannot** define it *without specifying a basis*.

What an *engineer* calls a *vector* (i.e., a sequence of numbers), a
*mathematician* calls a coordinate representation of an (abstract) vector in a
specific basis.
IOW, when you *define*

```
a + [b,c,d,...] := [a+b,a+c,a+d,...]
```

what I see is that you have selected an *arbitrary* vector (of huge norm!)
`Y=[1,1,1,...]` and defined

```
a + X := a*Y + X
```

but why select this specific vector? how is it better than any other one?
We all love the canonical basis, but in a different basis this vector may look
different!

The current behavior can lead to actual *errors*, e.g., if someone wants to add a random error and writes

```
my_vector + np.random.normal()     # WRONG! each component gets the SAME error!
```

instead of the correct one

```
my_vector + np.random.normal(size=len(my_vector))
```

Also, when dealing with *matrices*, which *are* a
[ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)),
so they *do* have a canonical non-0 element - the
[unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory)),
the numpy behavior is completely counter-intuitive!

```
10 + array([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

should be `array([[11,2],[3,14]])`, *not* `array([[11,12],[13,14]])`!
(for the same reason: matrices are just representations of linear operators, and
they look different in different bases).

Note that the unit matrix is the *same* in any basis.

Please see [Can you add a scalar to a matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1379234/37092) for a similar explanation in 2d.

Comment: What's the difference between multiplying each element of an array by a scalar, and adding the scalar to each element of the array? Anyways, there isn't a way to tell `numpy` to not do this.  You'll have to write your own `add` function that tests for scalar arguments and raises its own error.

Comment: Does this help [Can you add a scalar to a matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1379234/can-you-add-a-scalar-to-a-matrix)? This also seems to be a common abbreviation in mathematics. I think a `LinearAlgebraError` would confuse a lot of `numpy` users.

Comment: `numpy` does not attempt to conform to Linear Algebra.  Note that even MATLAB, which fits most peoples' intuitions about Linear Algebra better, permits the addition of a matrix and scalar (though its `scalars` are still (1,1) size matrices).  The `sympy.Matrix` class behaves more as you want.

Comment: okay, @hpaulj, I added an mathy rationale. I hope I made the explanation clear...